# Mathjax not interpreted in GWT frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, gwt, mathjax

In my GWT project I have a draft page in which users type some text mixed with TeX and when the draft is published they see the text and the compiled TeX. This is achieved through MathJax and it is working well.

The aim is to add to the draft page an iFrame in which users could see a preview of the compiled text+TeX before publication, so I added a GWT Frame to my page and a Preview button to trigger the fetch of the input text from the editor and the visualization in an environment with MathJax active (the iFrame).

[image]

To do this, I added an `@UiHandler("previewButton")` which on click performs this:

```
public void previewButtonClick(ClickEvent event){

    if (previewButton.getText().equals("Preview")){
        previewButton.setText("Hide Preview");
        abstractPreview.setVisible(true);
        abstractPreview.setSize("100%", "550px");
        abstractPreview.setStyleName("shownFrame");
        IFrameElement iframe = IFrameElement.as(abstractPreview.getElement());
        Document iFrameContent = iframe.getContentDocument();

        iFrameContent.getHead().setInnerHTML(
                "<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">" +
                "    MathJax.Hub.Config({" +
                "      jax: [\"input/TeX\", \"output/HTML-CSS\"]," +
                "      extensions: [\"tex2jax.js\"]," +
                "      \"HTML-CSS\": { preferredFont: \"TeX\", availableFonts: [\"STIX\",\"TeX\"] }," +
                "      tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ [\"$\", \"$\"], [\"\\\\(\",\"\\\\)\"] ], displayMath: [ [\"$$\",\"$$\"], [\"\\\\[\", \"\\\\]\"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: \"tex2jax_ignore|dno\" },\n" +
                "      TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: \"red\", mathbackground: \"#FFEEEE\", mathsize: \"90%\" } } }," +
                "      messageStyle: \"none\"" +
                "    });" +
                "" +
                "    </script>" +
                "    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js\"></script>");

        iFrameContent.getBody().setInnerHTML(summary.getText());
```

where the `summary.getText()` contains the input text.

The problem is that when I click the Preview button the Frame opens and I see the input text as-is, without the MathJax compilation. In the console it seems well loaded and without errors.

In fact, inspecting the code of the iFrame and copy/pasting the html into a local file it displays correctly the input text, interpreted by MathJax!